Replacing tank water heater to tankless water heater
First time replacing a tank heater to tankless natural gas water heater. I’ve done a couple of bathroom remodels with some experience with soldering copper pipes.
Have a few questions(sorry if some of these may sound silly).

while working on replacing heater, is it ok to connect cold to hot line with braided steel hose or flexible corrugated pipe?
Installing 3 way valve to close off water heater when troubleshooting (is this a good idea or totally unnecessary? I’m aware turning off gas to WH will work as well). Should I use a hard copper pipe between the 3 way valves or can use flex copper pipe as well?
ok to connect 3 way valve to isolation valve with flex copper pipe or best to use hard copper pipe and what’s minimum length for connection?
will make my own sediment trap for gas line. Will use yellow pipe dope.
use PVC vent pipes (per manufacturer instructions)since I’m using a non condensing tank. Will be pushing 2” pvc pipe thru existing metal vent pipe to roof. I’ll cap end of pipe but drill holes on cap and sides of pipe for venting.
Whats the proper way to drain a 50 gallon tank? Do I just turn off pilot light, then turn off water and gas?
Will disconnecting water lines help empty the tank or do I need to open a faucet or remove the pressure relief valve?



Tankless heaters use a large amount of gas or electricity when heating the water.  You might need larger gas line for it to work.  The electric ones can use up to 120 amps compared to 30 amps for a tank heater.  Imagine it is almost the same for gas.

To drain, you want a hot water faucet/tap above to be open to let air in, cold water off/stopped, power/gas off, and some place to drain 50 gallons(sump pump).

Hi crip659, Noritz manual states 3/4” gas line is adequate.  Thanks for the tips on draining tank.

TLDR, Too many questions in one, but definitely no on the braided steel hose. (it's rubber inside)

RMDman I apologize for al the ?s.  Thanks for tip on braided lines.

Have you read through the installation manual? The ones I've installed actually ask you to do specific valves and fittings on the inlet and outlet so you can descale the unit in the future.

KMJ - I’ll be installing the isolation valves as well for descaling.
